# How to reduce video size with php script?

Tags: php, video, filesize

i have an PHP Application where registered users upload their video. Here i want to reduce file size of video while uploading.

Is there any solution with PHP language?

Comment: Try using http://zencoder.com/en/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about php but i can suggest you to upload to a web server that supports **FFMPEG** Project

so by specifying video resolution  you can reduce file size

```
ffmpeg -i <inputfilename> -s 640x480 -b 512k -vcodec mpeg1video -acodec copy
```

hope this will help you